# How to draw an image over a background image

Tags: java, image, swing

Hey so im trying to make a D&D game for a school project. When I draw my background image it works and draws it. But when I draw my background image and my player image only the player image shows up. 
[My Code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rMzSfYX4HPMfhiXnV64ROszMBkr78jgS?usp=sharing)

Comment: *"My Code"* Eaqch question should be accompanied by a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Post it ***here*** as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So, your basic problem can be summed up here...

```
public class UIFrame extends JFrame {
     //...
     public UIFrame() {
        setSize(size);
        add(background);
        add(userScreen);
```

Two thins are wrong with this.  First, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` to layout it's components, meaning that only the last component added will actually be laid out.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Second, components are painted in LIFO order, so in your case, that would be `userScreen` then `background` - but since `background` is never laid out (it's size is `0x0`) you won't see it.

The reason I mention it is because, you shouldn't be trying to design you program this way.

Next issue ...

```
public static Image[] scheme_player = new Image[1];
public static boolean imagesLoaded = false;
public static boolean leftPress = false;
public static boolean rightPress = false;
public static boolean upPress = false;
public static boolean downPress = false;
public static boolean mouseClick = false;
```

This is a pretty good sign of a bad design. `static` is not your friend and can lead to some very interesting (and difficult to debug) behaviour

Instead, we want to think about your design from in a more agnostic manner.

## Disclaimer

This is an "example", intended to provide a "base line" of ideas from which you can grow your own API/concept from.  There are some things in the example which I might do differently if I were designing my own solution, but have been done for brevity and to reduce the overall complexity

## Basic concepts

You have stuff that paints, you have stuff that moves, you probably have stuff that collides and other stuff to.  You need some way to manage and coordinate all this "stuff"

A basic principle of OOP (and programming in general) is the concept of "model-view-controller".  The idea is to seperate your concepts into smaller, decoupled units of work, which can then be put back together, in what ever way you need, to form a large picture (or body of work)

So, let's start with the basic building blocks, the "entity".  A "entity" is something in your program which carries information and may perform different tasks and roles.  Because you might have any number of types of entities, I would start with a series of basic interfaces which describe basic behaviour of different types of entities...

```
public interface Entity {
    // Other common properties
}

public interface MovableEntity extends Entity {
    public void move(GameModel model);
    // Other "movable" entities might also have
    // speed adjustments, but I might consider those as
    // seperate entities in of themselves, but that's me
}

public interface PaintableEntity extends Entity {
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model);
}
```

Notice, I didn't make movable or paintable into a single entity (you could create a fourth `interface` which does), this is because you might have a movable entity which isn't painted or a painted entity which doesn't move, like the background!

Next, we need some kind container to hold the important information which the rest of the game might need in order to do their jobs, some kind of, model!

```
public interface GameModel {

    public enum Input {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public boolean hasInput(Input input);
    public Dimension getViewableArea();

    // Other properties which might be needed by the
    // entities
}
```

This is pretty basic, but this is the concept around which information is shared. Here I've focused only on those elements which the entities really needed (no need to expose functionality that they don't really need).

I've also prepared the state for "input", which is agnostic from how that input actually occurs.  The rest of the API doesn't care, they only want to know if the input is available or not.

From this, I can start building some basic entities...

```
public class BackgroundEntity implements PaintableEntity {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Dimension bounds = model.getViewableArea();
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }

}

public class PlayerEntity implements PaintableEntity, MovableEntity {

    private int speed = 2;
    private int x, y;

    public PlayerEntity() {
        // load the player image
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void move(GameModel model) {
        int speed = getSpeed();
        int x = getX();
        int y = getY();

        if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.UP)) {
            y -= speed;
        } else if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.DOWN)) {
            y += speed;
        }
        if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.LEFT)) {
            x -= speed;
        } else if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.RIGHT)) {
            x += speed;
        }

        Dimension bounds = model.getViewableArea();
        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y + 10 > bounds.height) {
            y = bounds.height - 10;
        }
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x + 10 > bounds.width) {
            x = bounds.width - 10;
        }

        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

}
```

Okay, that's all fine and good, but we need some way to actually update the state, in this case, we devise a concept of mutable model.  The intent been to "hide" functionality, so we don't expose it to parts of the API which don't need (the player doesn't need to be able to add/remove new entities)

```
public interface MutableGameModel extends GameModel {

    public void setInput(Input input, boolean enabled);

    public void add(Entity entity);
    public void remove(Entity entity);

    public void update();

    // Decision, who needs access to these lists
    public List<PaintableEntity> paintableEntities();
    public List<MovableEntity> moveableEntities();
}
```

And because we actually need some way to work...

```
public class DefaultGameModel implements MutableGameModel {

    private Set<Input> inputs = new HashSet<>();
    private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>(25);

    @Override
    public boolean hasInput(Input input) {
        return inputs.contains(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(Input input, boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            inputs.add(input);
        } else {
            inputs.remove(input);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getViewableArea() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public void update() {
        for (MovableEntity entity : moveableEntities()) {
            entity.move(this);
        }
    }

    // This is not the most efficent approach. You might consider 
    // caching each entity type into seperate lists when they are added
    // instead
    public List<PaintableEntity> paintableEntities() {
        return entities.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e instanceof PaintableEntity)
                        .map(e -> (PaintableEntity) e)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<MovableEntity> moveableEntities() {
        return entities.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e instanceof MovableEntity)
                        .map(e -> (MovableEntity) e)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Entity entity) {
        entities.add(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Entity entity) {
        entities.remove(entity);
    }

}
```

This is pretty basic concept, but it puts into place the foundations of the rest of work - please not this is a "EXAMPLE", I've cut some corners for brevity and so I could get it up and running quickly, but the basic concept should hold up

And finally, we get to the "view" (and controller).  This is the part where we monitor for input states, update the model accordingly, run the main loop to update the model state, based on the current inputs, schedule and performing painting

```
public class GamePane extends JPanel {

    private MutableGameModel model;

    public GamePane(MutableGameModel model) {
        this.model = model;

        setupBindings();

        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.update();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setupBindings() {
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.released");

        actionMap.put("Up.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.UP, true));
        actionMap.put("Up.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.UP, false));
        actionMap.put("Down.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.DOWN, true));
        actionMap.put("Down.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.DOWN, false));
        actionMap.put("Left.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.LEFT, true));
        actionMap.put("Left.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.LEFT, false));
        actionMap.put("Right.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.RIGHT, true));
        actionMap.put("Right.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.RIGHT, false));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return model.getViewableArea().getSize();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (PaintableEntity entity : model.paintableEntities()) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            entity.paint(g2d, model);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}

public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

    private MutableGameModel model;
    private GameModel.Input input;
    private boolean pressed;

    public InputAction(MutableGameModel model, GameModel.Input input, boolean pressed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.input = input;
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.setInput(input, pressed);
    }

}
```

Pretty simple :P

The solution makes use of the [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which is generally less troublesome them `KeyListener` and should be used in 99% of cases you want to monitor a subset of input.

I've also used a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as my "main-loop". This is a safer option (in Swing) as it does not violate the single threaded nature of the API

## Example...

Because I know how hard it can be to try and put together "snippets" of code...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultGameModel model = new DefaultGameModel();
                model.add(new BackgroundEntity());
                model.add(new PlayerEntity());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GamePane(model));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private MutableGameModel model;

        public GamePane(MutableGameModel model) {
            this.model = model;

            setupBindings();

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    model.update();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        public void setupBindings() {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.released");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.released");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.released");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.released");

            actionMap.put("Up.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.UP, true));
            actionMap.put("Up.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.UP, false));
            actionMap.put("Down.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.DOWN, true));
            actionMap.put("Down.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.DOWN, false));
            actionMap.put("Left.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.LEFT, true));
            actionMap.put("Left.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.LEFT, false));
            actionMap.put("Right.pressed", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.RIGHT, true));
            actionMap.put("Right.released", new InputAction(model, GameModel.Input.RIGHT, false));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return model.getViewableArea().getSize();
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (PaintableEntity entity : model.paintableEntities()) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                entity.paint(g2d, model);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

        private MutableGameModel model;
        private GameModel.Input input;
        private boolean pressed;

        public InputAction(MutableGameModel model, GameModel.Input input, boolean pressed) {
            this.model = model;
            this.input = input;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.setInput(input, pressed);
        }

    }

    public class DefaultGameModel implements MutableGameModel {

        private Set<Input> inputs = new HashSet<>();
        private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>(25);

        @Override
        public boolean hasInput(Input input) {
            return inputs.contains(input);
        }

        @Override
        public void setInput(Input input, boolean enabled) {
            if (enabled) {
                inputs.add(input);
            } else {
                inputs.remove(input);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getViewableArea() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void update() {
            for (MovableEntity entity : moveableEntities()) {
                entity.move(this);
            }
        }

        // This is not the most efficent approach. You might consider 
        // caching each entity type into seperate lists when they are added
        // instead
        public List<PaintableEntity> paintableEntities() {
            return entities.stream()
                            .filter(e -> e instanceof PaintableEntity)
                            .map(e -> (PaintableEntity) e)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public List<MovableEntity> moveableEntities() {
            return entities.stream()
                            .filter(e -> e instanceof MovableEntity)
                            .map(e -> (MovableEntity) e)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Entity entity) {
            entities.add(entity);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(Entity entity) {
            entities.remove(entity);
        }

    }

    public interface GameModel {

        public enum Input {
            UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
        }

        public boolean hasInput(Input input);

        public Dimension getViewableArea();

        // Other properties which might be needed by the
        // entities
    }

    public interface MutableGameModel extends GameModel {

        public void setInput(Input input, boolean enabled);

        public void add(Entity entity);
        public void remove(Entity entity);

        public void update();

        // Decision, who needs access to these lists
        public List<PaintableEntity> paintableEntities();
        public List<MovableEntity> moveableEntities();
    }

    public interface Entity {
        // Other common properties
    }

    public interface MovableEntity extends Entity {

        public void move(GameModel model);
        // Other "movable" entities might also have
        // speed adjustments, but I might consider those as
        // seperate entities in of themselves, but that's me
    }

    public interface PaintableEntity extends Entity {

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model);
    }

    public class BackgroundEntity implements PaintableEntity {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Dimension bounds = model.getViewableArea();
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }

    }

    public class PlayerEntity implements PaintableEntity, MovableEntity {

        private int speed = 2;
        private int x, y;

        public PlayerEntity() {
            // load the player image
        }

        public int getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, GameModel model) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 10, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void move(GameModel model) {
            int speed = getSpeed();
            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();

            if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.UP)) {
                y -= speed;
            } else if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.DOWN)) {
                y += speed;
            }
            if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.LEFT)) {
                x -= speed;
            } else if (model.hasInput(GameModel.Input.RIGHT)) {
                x += speed;
            }

            Dimension bounds = model.getViewableArea();
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y + 10 > bounds.height) {
                y = bounds.height - 10;
            }
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            } else if (x + 10 > bounds.width) {
                x = bounds.width - 10;
            }

            setX(x);
            setY(y);
        }

    }

}
```

*nb* - For every one whose going to tell more how horribly inefficient it is to use `List#stream` this way, yes, you are correct, I've mentioned that several times - the point for using is brevity.

If I was doing this, I'd either constraint the requirements at the `MutableModelLevel` (using things like `add(PaintableEntity)` or have the add method determine which series of `List`s the entity needs to be added to) or make a series of generic "models" which constraint the functionality, so that when I devise my implementation, I can pick and choose which functionality I want to use - but that's just me

Answer (score 0):

Well does your player have transparency? If the player doesn't have alpha then it will draw over the bg.

Also, I would recommend using this render method instead in conjunction with a proper game loop:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT); // background (can also be an image)

    player.render(g2d); // player

    g2d.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```