# Calling method using KeyBindings

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, key-bindings

I'm creating a 2d game, where the players can shoot bullets. I'm trying to figure out how to call the shoot method when a player presses a key. I'm using Key Bindings, which is new to me. I have read the API but still can't get it work. Suggestions would be helpful

Here is my code for Keyboard input:

```
public PlayerTwo (){
    playertwo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("cal.png");
    bullets = new ArrayList();
    tm.start();
    InputMap im = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up.pressed");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "up.released");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down.pressed");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "down.released");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left.pressed");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "left.released");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right.pressed");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "right.released");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "space.pressed");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "space.released");


    am.put("up.pressed", new MoveAction(-1, 0));
    am.put("up.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
    am.put("down.pressed", new MoveAction(1, 0));
    am.put("down.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
    am.put("left.pressed", new MoveAction(0, -1));
    am.put("left.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
    am.put("right.pressed", new MoveAction(0, 1));
    am.put("right.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
    //Shoot.getActionMap();

}
```

Comment: `am.put("space.pressed", new ShootAction())`; <- You need to create a `ShootAction` class which changes the state of the "shoot" flag, through which your "main-loop" can make decisions about what should be done

Comment: Could I just  rewrite my bullet class to change the state?

Comment: I'd avoid it, as you're coupling the logic. Better to have the "shoot action" change the state of the model/controller and let it decide what that actually means

Comment: There are plenty of examples laying around, [this is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612426/how-to-draw-an-image-over-a-background-image/50613543#50613543) I did recently which demonstrates the idea a decoupled work flow

Answer (score 0):

The Key bindings (and Action) API attempt to decouple the concept of "input" from "action".  This allows you to have multiple types of "inputs" which can all trigger the same action.

For example, you might have buttons, key board strokes, joy stick or other external controller, all capable of generating a "shoot" input. Rather then having to write code for each of these inputs which "eventually" triggers some action.  You can simply bind them all to a single "action" in a succinct manner which is decoupled from each other (the way you might bind the joy stick input would be different then for buttons or key strokes).

So, the first thing we need is someway to indicate that the "trigger" has been pulled (or released), maybe something like...

```
public class ShootAction extends AbstractAction {
    private boolean isShooting;

    public ShootAction(boolean isShooting) {
        this.isShooting = isShooting;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Okay, well, that's kind of boring and doesn't actually "do" anything.  What we need is some kind of "state manager" who we can tell that the trigger has been pressed or released.  It's important to note, it's not the `ShootAction`s responsibility to decide "what" or "how" shooting occur, it should be focused purely on notifying the "model" or "controller" that the state has changed so it can react to it in some meaningful way.

So, assuming we have some controller which provides the shooting state management...

```
public class SomeAwesomeGameController ... {
    public void setShooting(boolean shooting) {...}
    public boolean isShooting() {...}
}
```

We can pass an instance of it to the action and use it to update the state...

```
public class ShootAction extends AbstractAction {
    private boolean isShooting;
    private SomeAwesomeGameController controller;

    public ShootAction(SomeAwesomeGameController controller, boolean isShooting) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.isShooting = isShooting;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        controller.setShooting(isShooting);
    }
}
```

One of the reasons for doing it this way (apart from decoupling the code) is because there is a OS delay between the first key stroke and repeated key strokes. By removing the need to rely on the actual repeated events (only caring when the state changes), we remove this delay.

And finally, we can bind it all together :P

```
public class PlayerTwo ... {

    // Don't forget to assign this value ;)
    private SomeAwesomeGameController controller;

    public PlayerTwo() {

        InputMap im = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "space.pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "space.released");

        am.put("space.pressed", new ShootAction(controller, true));
        am.put("space.released", new ShootAction(controller, false));
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm also having trouble adding the input to my main game class do you have any suggestions?